# Escape dash sign of bash history command

Tags: bash, history

On my Ubuntu system, I would like to use bash history command to remember some commands, but when I enter command like:

```
history -s "-t tag_name"
```

bash report error:

```
bash: history: -t: invalid option
history: usage: history [-c] [-d offset] [n] or history -anrw [filename] or history -ps arg [arg...]
```

It seems the argument of `-s` option cannot start with dash sign, because when I enter something like

```
history -s "echo test"
```

it works fine.

How can I make history to remember a command starts with dash sign? (Without adding leading white spaces)

Comment: I'm surprised the error message only mentions `-t`; `-t tag_name` is being passed as a single argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can signal `history` that you are done passing arguments, so it does not try to evaluate `-t`, like so:

```
history -s -- "-t tag_name"
```